# Change name of work on CV

Tags: resume, ethics, work-experience

I am doing casual teaching at my University (Tutoring, marking assignments and answering student questions).

I am a data science student, and the papers that I am helping with are related to data science.

When I add the role to my CV, I do not want to write "Teaching Assistance" (Even though the name is Casual Teaching assistance) I want to write something "Data or Analytics" Teaching assistance because I am there not because my teaching is good, but because I am doing something related to data science.

Am I thinking wrong? I know I will explain everything under the title, but I am thinking the title related to being work as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The job title you put on your CV should always match what your employer would give should anyone ask them to confirm your employment (for a background check or reference).

If you're concerned that the title doesn't accurately reflect what you're doing or that it might harm your future applications then the best approach is to talk to your manager about getting it officially updated.

Honestly though as long as you're accurately reflecting your responsibilities in the description it's unlikely to make a massive difference - but I can understand the position that everything helps.

Answer (score 7):

*Generally* you should leave the title as given to you.

You should give a more detailed description of your duties after the title row.